# Validate MM/DD string in SSRS

Tags: regex, ssrs-2008

I have a text parameter in one of my reports where the user enters a string. I need to validate two things.

1) Whether the entered value is in MM/DD format

2) If the entered value is in MM/DD format, then I need to check whether is it valid MM/DD value. For example if user enters 02/29,02/28,03/31 etc which are valid values. If user enters 02/30, 04/31, 07/32 etc then these values are invalid.

Please help in achieving the above two validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could validate this parameter by creating a variable for assessing the validity and then using this variable to show or hide report items and an error message, I think it might be more elegant to simply use the existing date/time data type for your parameter and then use the `DatePart()` function in SSRS or SQL to pick out the day and month for whatever report purposes you need. Barring that, you could write an expression like this to test for a valid date:

```
 =IsDate(Parameters!Date.Value + "/2016")
```